# MFC ComboBox with graphics?

Tags: graphics, combobox, mfc

Is there a standard, built-in or library available for MFC where a combobox can list graphic icons instead of text or even something like a listview with text and icons instead of just text?

Just don't feel like reinventing the wheel with owner-draw type stuff if already done.

TIA!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at using [`CComboBoxEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/using-ccomboboxex?view=vs-2019).

To quote:

> The extended combo box control is an extension of the standard combo
>   box control that **provides native support for item images**. These images
>   can be used to indicate the status of individual items in the combo
>   box, such as the currently selected and unselected items. To make item
>   images easily accessible, the control provides image list support.
>
> Use this control to provide the functionality of a combo box without
>   having to manually draw item graphics.

Comment: Great info, no wonder I couldn't find anything searching the Internet when you have people voting the question down.   I'm sure many others will find the question and answer useful.